# Best practice for profiling web pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, profiling

I am trying to profile pages in my application. I would like to ask for best practices to follow to do this job either

- at an early stage by the developer using tools as Chrome Developer tool
- at the staging phase by using third party tools and methods

Which are the best way to do this? What are tools available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very big topic. The book [Performance Analysis for Java WebSites](http://www.linbai.info/computers-it/performance-analysis-for-java-websites.html) has much applicable wisdom.

One idea I find valuable: start profiling early. Once you've got even a partially stubbed implementation it can be load tested. Do that regularly and you spot the bad behaviours as they are introduced.

Comment: Sorry I did not specified but I am looking at something tailored for the ASP.NET platform

Comment: A great deal of the approach in the book I reference Is transferable. Of course the tools are specific but the core ideas apply generally.